# Does snaps slow down the boot?

Tags: boot, mount, performance, snap

When we use the command `lsblk`, we can see that each snap application is mounted under the directory `/snap/app_name`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk   
├─sda1   8:1    0  61.5G  0 part  
├─sda2   8:2    0 337.7G  0 part  
├─sda3   8:3    0  62.4G  0 part /  
└─sda4   8:4    0   4.1G  0 part [SWAP]  
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom    
loop0    7:0    0  29.7M  0 loop /snap/wifi-ap/93  
loop1    7:1    0  78.4M  0 loop /snap/core/1577  
loop2    7:2    0  79.5M  1 loop /snap/core/1689
```

So does this mounting on boot slow down the boot process ?

Comment: In general all mount actions have impact because Ubuntu will run `fsck` on each partition before mounting. So you may want to consider mounting partitions  manually if they are not required during boot.

Comment: And it would be interesting, how to delay the mount process:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/649421/delay-the-mounting-of-snap-images-after-the-login

Answer (score 9):

You can probably get more detail about what's consuming resources during bootup using the `systemd-analyze` command. For example:-

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

This will list in order of time used, each thing that consumed time during boot.

```
systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg
```

This will generate an svg called "plot.svg" which you can open using an image viewer app. It shows graphically what's eating up your machine during boot.

Comment: the graphic is just hundredts of pink lines, no use

Comment: the lines show what is running when. use `systemd-analyze critical-chain` for whats blocking boot

Answer (score 3):

Someone already Explain it.

Using Snaps for having up-to-date software, we end up paying for it with higher network traffic, more disk usage and slower boot time. If you do not want to use Snaps at all, then remove them with sudo apt-get purge snapd.

See more here [Details about Snap Mount](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056841/1035579)

Comment: That post is from 2018, by now snap improved a lot, so there might not be such a boot time malus anyone

Comment: Yes, correct. Thanks for informations