# Very slow boot up Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

When I install Ubuntu and Windows 7 on Dual Boot my Ubuntu is booted up very slow.

```
$ sudo blkid
    /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="9ECA279CCA277027" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="719663af-01"
    /dev/sda2: UUID="C4E22C86E22C7F34" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="719663af-02"
    /dev/sdb1: LABEL="MAGACIN" UUID="62B8F4AFB8F482B9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="d1a93929-01"
    /dev/sdb5: UUID="0e0cc1cc-a2e6-477d-95c4-232979d32c86" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d1a93929-05"
    /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Systemd-analyze blame

```
25.275s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         21.048s dev-sdb5.device
         12.487s preload.service
         10.656s systemd-journal-flush.service
         10.277s dev-loop20.device
         10.277s dev-loop18.device
         10.276s dev-loop19.device
         10.276s dev-loop17.device
         10.275s dev-loop16.device
         10.275s dev-loop15.device
         10.275s dev-loop13.device
         10.274s dev-loop14.device
         10.274s dev-loop12.device
         10.274s dev-loop9.device
         10.272s dev-loop11.device
         10.272s dev-loop10.device
         10.272s dev-loop8.device
         10.124s dev-loop4.device
         10.124s dev-loop3.device
         10.122s dev-loop5.device
         10.121s dev-loop1.device
         10.117s dev-loop6.device
         10.116s dev-loop7.device
         10.115s dev-loop2.device
         10.114s dev-loop0.device
         10.090s dev-loop23.device
         10.089s dev-loop21.device
         10.055s dev-loop22.device
         10.026s dev-loop24.device
          9.857s alsa-restore.service
          7.560s apparmor.service
          6.644s grub-common.service
          6.119s lm-sensors.service
          6.064s speech-dispatcher.service
          5.831s stunnel4.service
          5.407s systemd-logind.service
          5.295s apport.service
          5.070s networkd-dispatcher.service
          5.059s tor.service
          5.059s pppd-dns.service
          5.058s gpu-manager.service
          4.901s thermald.service
          4.859s rsyslog.service
          3.599s NetworkManager.service
          3.411s tor@default.service
          3.380s gdm.service
          3.353s windscribe-cli.service
          2.870s snapd.seeded.service
          2.392s snapd.service
          2.031s snap-discord-69.mount
          2.003s wpa_supplicant.service
          1.852s snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-81.mount
          1.828s snap-core-4917.mount
          1.801s snap-obs\x2dstudio-104.mount
          1.673s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.654s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.636s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
          1.627s snap-obs\x2dstudio-55.mount
          1.616s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
          1.606s snap-core-4830.mount
          1.571s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
          1.565s polkit.service
          1.563s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-101.mount
          1.527s snap-core-4650.mount
          1.500s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-62.mount
          1.481s systemd-udevd.service
          1.475s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
          1.469s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-178.mount
          1.452s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-64.mount
          1.402s snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-85.mount
          1.376s udisks2.service
          1.368s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-45.mount
          1.346s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-31.mount
          1.329s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-96.mount
          1.323s fwupd.service
          1.306s snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-77.mount
          1.106s networking.service
          1.046s keyboard-setup.service
           997ms dns-clean.service
           777ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
           777ms console-setup.service
           763ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           762ms dev-hugepages.mount
           760ms dev-mqueue.mount
           736ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           711ms qemu-kvm.service
           631ms packagekit.service
           529ms kerneloops.service
           448ms user@120.service
           384ms phpsessionclean.service
           376ms plymouth-start.service
           295ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           293ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-41.mount
           293ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-34.mount
           272ms systemd-journald.service
           264ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
           228ms accounts-daemon.service
           226ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-170.mount
           223ms systemd-resolved.service
           214ms ufw.service
           211ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           133ms systemd-sysctl.service
           128ms systemd-random-seed.service
           103ms user@1000.service
            86ms resolvconf.service
            82ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            79ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            77ms upower.service
            60ms bolt.service
            57ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            54ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            43ms systemd-modules-load.service
            32ms dev-loop25.device
            31ms colord.service
            15ms setvtrgb.service
            14ms ModemManager.service
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             7ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
             6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             5ms openvpn.service
             4ms avahi-daemon.service
             4ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
           840us snapd.socket
lines 104-126/126 (END)
           103ms user@1000.service
            86ms resolvconf.service
            82ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            79ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            77ms upower.service
            60ms bolt.service
            57ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            54ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            43ms systemd-modules-load.service
            32ms dev-loop25.device
            31ms colord.service
            15ms setvtrgb.service
            14ms ModemManager.service
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             7ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
             6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             5ms openvpn.service
             4ms avahi-daemon.service
             4ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
           840us snapd.socket
```

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4,2G     0  4,2G   0% /dev
tmpfs           837M  2,0M  835M   1% /run
/dev/sdb5        76G   20G   52G  28% /
tmpfs           4,2G  108M  4,1G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,3M  4,1k  5,3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4,2G     0  4,2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      143M  143M     0 100% /snap/discord/69
/dev/loop1       60M   60M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/81
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop3      137M  137M     0 100% /snap/obs-studio/104
/dev/loop4      136M  136M     0 100% /snap/obs-studio/55
/dev/loop6       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop5       14M   14M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop7      2,5M  2,5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop8       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop9      147M  147M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/62
/dev/loop11     2,5M  2,5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/178
/dev/loop12     147M  147M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop14      14M   14M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/96
/dev/loop15      61M   61M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/77
/dev/loop13      60M   60M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/85
/dev/loop17      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop10     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop16     4,0M  4,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/45
/dev/loop18      14M   14M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/101
/dev/loop19      23M   23M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/31
/dev/loop20      37M   37M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop21     4,0M  4,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41
/dev/loop23     2,5M  2,5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/170
/dev/loop22      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/34
/dev/loop24     4,0M  4,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop25     132k  132k     0 100% /tmp/selftest-mountpoint-488465102
tmpfs           837M   17k  837M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           837M   25k  837M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I really need help. I tried it in various ways, but it did not work either

Comment: What kernel is being used `uname -a`

Comment: @Jeremy31 krenel: Linux overflow 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: show us output from  `df -H`

Comment: @ScottStensland I did

Comment: What says `hdparm -d /dev/sdb` (assuming you are booting on `/dev/sdb`)

Comment: just after a slow boot up from a terminal issue `dmesg`  ... look for clues ...   `dmesg|grep 'gave up waiting for'`

Comment: @xenoid dev/sdb:
 HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: The radical method is to remove Snappy subsystem (all mounts of `/dev/loop*` to /snap/*). Or reduce the number of snaps - save only used ones and/or remove/replace others with deb-packages. See related [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056841/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert How to remove Snappy?

Comment: @N0rbert ok, I removed this and again 25 sec to boot.

Comment: @Itra If you use HDD, then 25 seconds is normal value.