# Very slow load on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am completely new to Linux so apologies in advance!

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a wiped machine and everything seems to work well except that it takes about 2 mins to boot.

Here are some details that might be useful for diagnostics (judging by other posts I've seen on similar issues).

The output of "systemd-analyze" is

> Startup finished in 1min 43.839s (kernel) + 7.763s (userspace) = 1min 51.603s 
>   graphical.target reached after 7.758s in userspace

The output of "sudo blkid" is

> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/sda: PTUUID="8f39e0f9" PTTYPE="dos"
>   /dev/sdb5: UUID="92b37aee-3acf-447e-b15e-2fbb8a83e9a7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7ff18de1-05"
>   /dev/sdb6: UUID="21d2706c-8400-44f6-ad90-79d2dfb6384f" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="7ff18de1-06"

(the sda is an older hard-drive (not SSD) that I want to just use for backing up some files).

The content of "/etc/fstab" is

> UUID=92b37aee-3acf-447e-b15e-2fbb8a83e9a7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1 
>   UUID=21d2706c-8400-44f6-ad90-79d2dfb6384f none            swap    sw              0       0

Hope this helps you diagnose my problem and suggest some things to try! Many thanks!

**EDIT.** In response to request here is the output of "systemd-analyze blame"

> 6.345s NetworkManager-wait-online.service 
>             4.481s plymouth-quit-wait.service 
>              834ms fwupd.service
>              639ms dev-sdb5.device
>              591ms ufw.service
>              459ms udisks2.service
>              448ms NetworkManager.service
>              442ms plymouth-start.service
>              395ms networkd-dispatcher.service
>              392ms snapd.service
>              294ms accounts-daemon.service
>              284ms dev-loop0.device
>              268ms ModemManager.service
>              264ms apparmor.service
>              256ms dev-loop2.device
>              243ms dev-loop3.device
>              238ms dev-loop1.device
>              213ms systemd-logind.service
>              197ms dev-loop4.device
>              191ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
>              181ms dev-loop5.device
>              170ms systemd-timesyncd.service
>              166ms systemd-udevd.service

It goes on but they're all very small times (should I still list them?)

Comment: Please add output of `systemd-analyze blame` to the question. If you see many `/dev/loop` devices, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056841/66509).

Comment: Added systemd-analyze blame output

Comment: I do not see anything critical here.

Comment: But why is the "kernel" taking over 90s during boot? Is that normal?

Comment: I have the same question about the kernel, you are right. But userspace loaded fasty. For kernel you can try to investigate logs for errors (`journalctl --dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/boot.log`).

Comment: That's actually not all that bad for 18.04 on an spinning disk

Comment: It’s actually on a 250GB SSD :S

Comment: When it is booting move your mouse around frantically to create more entropy and see if that speeds it up.

Comment: This didn’t work even though I was frantic :(

Comment: Take a look at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112587/solved-why-is-lubuntu-18-04-slow-to-start-up
My problem related to Intel graphics - could be your's is the same.