# Why is lubuntu (and Ubuntu) 18.04 slow to start up?

Tags: boot, 18.04, lubuntu

A new install (32bit, 3GB RAM) of Lubuntu 18.04:
It runs really well and fast (with all wanted apps installed LibreOffice etc) once started up but:

At boot: a screen full of what look like about 50 errors ending with **...flip-done timeout...**

Select OS screen - I choose Ubuntu

Blank screen: nothing for 50s

Blank screen: intermittent disk activity 4min

Login screen displayed: login very fast (about 7s).

These long delays also occur when going into Lock Screen.

Maybe a repeated attempt with timeout is slowing it?

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze blame
     1min 20.648s plymouth-start.service
           8.853s keyboard-setup.service
           8.079s systemd-journal-flush.service
           7.440s dev-sda5.device
           6.897s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           6.345s apt-daily-upgrade.service
           5.244s systemd-udevd.service
           5.193s systemd-sysctl.service
           3.782s udisks2.service
           3.415s NetworkManager.service
           2.718s ModemManager.service
           2.642s accounts-daemon.service
           2.542s upower.service
           2.415s grub-common.service
           2.353s gpu-manager.service
           2.321s networkd-dispatcher.service
           1.819s systemd-random-seed.service
           1.681s avahi-daemon.service
           1.066s systemd-modules-load.service
            798ms apparmor.service
            718ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            687ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            683ms dev-hugepages.mount
            682ms dev-mqueue.mount
            681ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            625ms polkit.service
            558ms swapfile.swap
            485ms systemd-resolved.service
            479ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            460ms apport.service
            434ms pppd-dns.service
            421ms lightdm.service
            415ms rsyslog.service
            413ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
            405ms systemd-journald.service
            400ms alsa-restore.service
            399ms plymouth-read-write.service
            383ms systemd-logind.service
            358ms systemd-rfkill.service
            329ms wpa_supplicant.service
            325ms ufw.service
            289ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            148ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            148ms user@1000.service
```

Also using `systemd-analyze` time:

```
Startup finished in 35.963s (kernel) + 1min 43.082s (userspace) = 2min 19.046s
graphical.target reached after 1min 43.069s in userspace
```

Also the kerneloops and two Network Manager lines were in red in the following:

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 43.069s
└─multi-user.target @1min 43.069s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 43.030s +36ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 43.027s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 36.128s +6.897s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 32.710s +3.415s
          └─dbus.service @1min 32.333s
            └─basic.target @1min 32.285s
              └─paths.target @1min 32.285s
                └─cups.path @1min 32.284s
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 32.247s
                    └─cryptsetup.target @1min 32.247s
                      └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @2.743s
                        └─-.mount @2.650s
                          └─system.slice @2.677s
                            └─-.slice @2.650s
```

This is now a dual-boot machine: that is Lubuntu 18.04 32bit installed alongside the previous Ubuntu 16.04. I worry slightly that the Lubuntu hasn't made its own swap partition and can't access the 16.04's swap partition?

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   5.6G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 366.2G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    94G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Try "fsck" fom live USB/ DVD.

Comment: Try ````systemd-analyze blame````. This will give a timing list of the systemd components involved in startup. You might see something there. Also look into the journal ````journalctl -r```` displays a listing from your logs with the most recent entries at the top. Press <space> to page down. You may see errors in there.

Comment: Vijay - I'm not sure what that fsck could be for.    

SB - I get systemd-analyse no such command

Comment: I'm not sure I can help, but `fsck` means file-system-check (fsck is the command). It's best run from a 'live' media (eg. your install media. you boot that and fsck your hdd partition) or when your disk isn't in use. If the system detects errors, it performs fsck on boot (consequence = slow boot).   The `systemd-analyze blame` command reports how many seconds each boot process took allowing you/us to see the major cause(s).  If you get an error, you should edit your question, and put the command+output into your question so we can see & provide clues & helpful advice.

Comment: Sorry SB - I used English spelling for analyze (analyse)!! Output now added to the question.

Comment: Hi! If it's solved, you can answer your own question below so people in the future can benefit from your solution.

Comment: Sorry Kuffy - I didn't know the protocol here - I hope this is now done correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine is a Dell Latitude D530 32bit with Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics. This problem seems quite widespread (turned out to be a bug in Ubuntu 18.04: [Bug #1767808 - Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1767808))

Kernel: 4.15.0-43

Firstly I used this to check for delays - very clearly highlighted in red on the commands output:

```
dmesg
```

Then I searched online and found this [Very long boot time and error messages on LM19 - Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=273797)

This solved the problem: Editing this file: /etc/default/grub

Altered the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=SVIDEO-1:d quiet splash"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot. Now it all moves super-fast!