# Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus Vivobook S take extra long to boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu, but Ubuntu takes far longer to boot. Windows 10 takes about 15 seconds, while it takes almost a minute to get to the Ubuntu login screen. The startup just doesn't feel right.

output of systemd-analyze blame:

```
20.604s dev-sda1.device
     17.790s dev-loop3.device
     17.743s dev-loop0.device
     17.684s dev-loop1.device
     17.356s dev-loop2.device
     17.210s dev-loop5.device
     17.206s dev-loop4.device
     17.141s dev-loop13.device
     17.105s dev-loop14.device
     17.091s dev-loop11.device
     17.064s dev-loop6.device
     17.018s dev-loop10.device
     16.965s dev-loop8.device
     16.859s dev-loop12.device
     16.843s dev-loop7.device
     16.610s dev-loop15.device
     16.151s dev-loop9.device
     16.036s systemd-udevd.service
      6.049s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.408s gpu-manager.service
      5.359s snapd.service
      4.272s networkd-dispatcher.service
      3.919s thermald.service
      3.697s NetworkManager.service
      3.257s udisks2.service
      2.497s systemd-journal-flush.service
      2.124s accounts-daemon.service
      1.966s networking.service
      1.894s ModemManager.service
      1.357s colord.service
      1.166s fwupd.service
      1.135s tlp.service
       916ms systemd-modules-load.service
       916ms systemd-sysctl.service
       884ms keyboard-setup.service
       881ms packagekit.service
       872ms polkit.service
       842ms snap-communitheme-1174.mount
       810ms snap-communitheme-1168.mount
       790ms grub-common.service
       784ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
       748ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-103.mount
       718ms snap-core-4917.mount
       666ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
       639ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
       592ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
       587ms apparmor.service
       565ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       564ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
       545ms speech-dispatcher.service
       543ms snap-core-5328.mount
       503ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
       480ms setvtrgb.service
       473ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-37.mount
       459ms console-setup.service
       445ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-43.mount
       394ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       391ms avahi-daemon.service
       390ms snap-libreoffice-80.mount
       364ms user@121.service
       329ms gdm.service
       321ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       307ms systemd-logind.service
       277ms bluetooth.service
       277ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       275ms ufw.service
       270ms lm-sensors.service
       268ms pppd-dns.service
       263ms rsyslog.service
       259ms plymouth-read-write.service
       254ms wpa_supplicant.service
       241ms upower.service
       223ms dev-hugepages.mount
       223ms dev-mqueue.mount
       205ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       201ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a67e8e78\x2d7b32\x2d4f85\x2db0f7\x2d5f112a9
       189ms systemd-journald.service
       177ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       176ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       175ms systemd-resolved.service
       168ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
       158ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
        90ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        82ms user@1000.service
        54ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9A77\x2dE65B.service
        53ms systemd-random-seed.service
        53ms bolt.service
        49ms dns-clean.service
        40ms snapd.seeded.service
        39ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        38ms apport.service
        23ms rtkit-daemon.service
        22ms alsa-restore.service
        13ms ureadahead-stop.service
         9ms kerneloops.service
         5ms boot-efi.mount
         5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
       712us snapd.socket
```

and output of systemd-analyze time:

```
Startup finished in 15.423s (kernel) + 34.495s (userspace) = 49.918s
```

graphical.target reached after 33.357s in userspace

Is this normal? The processor is Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8  with 16 GiB of RAM. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1056841/66509 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the dev-loop services that started on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056645/what-are-the-dev-loop-services-that-started-on-boot)