# resolvconf-pull-resolved.service and plymouth-quit-wait.service slows down my ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, plymouth, resolvconf

The problem is `resolveconf-pull-resolved.service` and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` are taking a lot of time to start making the overall boot process slow. The first one upon searching, I found various issues where it caused the boot to stuck there but none where it caused the boot to be slow overall, for the 2nd one I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168249/834982) answer which says that this service is not at fault as it just waits for others to complete.
The whole process of my investigation is explained below:

`systemd-analyze time` gives the following output:

```
Startup finished in 7.870s (firmware) + 3.118s (loader) + 19.467s (kernel) + 1min 56.978s (userspace) = 2min 27.435s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 56.840s in userspace
```

Upon following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109292/ubuntu-18-04-boot-time-is-very-slow-userspace-taking-a-lot-of-time) answer regarding slow userspace, mine problem was similar (meaning `snapd` was one of the main culprits for slow down ) as `systemd-analyze blame | grep snapd` gave the following output:

```
26.656s snapd.service                                                            
      1.011s snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
       915ms snapd.seeded.service                                                     
         1ms snapd.socket
```

and `systemd-analyze blame | grep dev-loop` gave

```
10.384s dev-loop19.device                                                        
     10.236s dev-loop9.device                                                         
     10.155s dev-loop0.device                                                         
     10.151s dev-loop16.device                                                        
     10.110s dev-loop14.device                                                        
      9.776s dev-loop13.device                                                        
      9.470s dev-loop15.device                                                        
      9.294s dev-loop12.device                                                        
      9.106s dev-loop6.device                                                         
      8.982s dev-loop17.device                                                        
      8.873s dev-loop11.device                                                        
      8.864s dev-loop10.device                                                        
      8.738s dev-loop8.device                                                         
      8.731s dev-loop18.device                                                        
      8.724s dev-loop21.device                                                        
      8.052s dev-loop3.device                                                         
      8.017s dev-loop2.device                                                         
      5.861s dev-loop5.device                                                         
      5.374s dev-loop1.device                                                         
      4.883s dev-loop4.device
```

But if we look at the whole plot in the [svg](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/berserker1/fac316c1821f144b11bffb50c359e315/raw/3d8354ef901953c8f2f679601314c070a04aab89/a.svg) file ( I have posted the link as uploading the whole image here would make it unreadable because of the size compression ) `resolveconf-pull-resolved.service` and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` still take more time than them. Below I have posted a screenshot showing the relevant section of the `svg` file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation yesterday and after some cleanup `resolveconf-pull-resolved.service` disappeared from the list and `plymouth-quit-wait.service` went back to third place. These are the steps I followed:

1. Remove all snaps installed in the past (`$ sudo snap remove xxx`) and reinstall the tools using other means like `apt` or with `deb` packages. That had a big improvement in my boot time (a lot of loopback devices were turned off). I couldn't completely get rid of snap because I'm using Gnome Desktop and it seems it was installed using snap during the OS installation.[This is my minimum snap list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3k7M.png)
2. Stop unused services (`$ sudo systemctl stop xxx` and `$ sudo systemctl disable xxx`). In my case, I stopped `PostgreSQL` (takes a lot of time), I also stopped `Apache`, `InfluxDB` and `OpenProject` (many services related)
3. Update the configuration of the System Journal following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094543/1083296).
4. Update the configuration of `apt-daily.service` so it triggers after boot. Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151760/why-is-my-start-up-is-ultra-slow) to know how.

After all of these actions, my boot time decreased dramatically. I'm thinking of using another Desktop manager like `Xfce` or uninstalling Gnome Desktop and reinstalling it without using Snaps.

As a side note, I am surprised at how little time it takes to start an application without snaps, for instance, VLC shows up almost instantly before took some seconds, close to 5-10.

Hope this helps!