# ubuntu 18.10 2 minutes to boot on ssd fresh install

Tags: boot, ssd, 18.10

here is the systemd-analyze

```
   systemd-analyze blame
     34.125s systemd-resolved.service
     33.952s systemd-timesyncd.service
     20.966s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      2.583s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.028s dev-sdb2.device
       764ms snapd.service
       373ms snap-vscode-77.mount
       356ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
       347ms fwupd.service
       336ms systemd-logind.service
       327ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
       313ms snap-opera-26.mount
       290ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
       288ms udisks2.service
       277ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-15.mount
       277ms dev-loop8.device
       274ms snap-discord-91.mount
       274ms dev-loop2.device
       265ms dev-loop1.device
       263ms dev-loop10.device
       254ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       250ms dev-loop9.device
       245ms ModemManager.service
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @56.369s
   └─multi-user.target @56.369s
     └─kerneloops.service @37.961s +10ms
        └─network-online.target @37.960s
         └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @35.376s +2.583s
          └─NetworkManager.service @35.229s +145ms
           └─dbus.service @35.225s
              └─basic.target @35.200s
                └─sockets.target @35.200s
                   └─snapd.socket @35.197s +2ms
                       └─sysinit.target @35.196s
                          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.242s +33.952s
                            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.223s +16ms
                              └─local-fs.target @1.219s
                               └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @37.720s
                                 └─run-user-1000.mount @35.701s
                                     └─local-fs-pre.target @232ms
                                       └─keyboard-setup.service 
                                                               @153ms+78ms
                                          └─systemdjournald.socket@144ms
                                          └─system.slice @143ms
```

please help me resolve the issue of ubuntu booting for 1-2min . first few launches it booted in 5-15seconds. (complete noob, using ubuntu for 3 hours)

edit: maybe my internal 1 tb hdd causes problems?

i mount it on boot and it mounts into /mnt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the dev-loop services that started on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056645/what-are-the-dev-loop-services-that-started-on-boot)