# UBUNTU 20.04 Slow to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the hard drive of a VIAO laptop model VGN-NW270F as a dual-boot with Windows 10. It started out working OK, but I had a lot of trouble sharing files with my Win 10 PC. Along the way Ubuntu started taking a long time to boot - 2-3 minutes.

I ran systemd-analyze time with results:

```
Startup finished in 39.111s (kernel) + 2min 28.126s (userspace) = 3min 7.237s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 28.047s in userspace
```

I ran systemd-analyze blame with results:

```
27.601s plymouth-quit-wait.service                         
16.406s dev-sda5.device                                    
16.137s snapd.service                                      
15.810s networkd-dispatcher.service                        
15.519s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                 
11.848s udisks2.service                                    
10.759s accounts-daemon.service                            
10.315s dev-loop16.device                                  
10.080s dev-loop10.device                                  
 9.854s dev-loop14.device                                  
 9.409s dev-loop13.device                                  
 9.199s dev-loop11.device                                  
 9.147s dev-loop17.device                                  
 9.098s dev-loop15.device                                  
 9.064s dev-loop12.device                                  
 8.803s dev-loop2.device                                   
 8.795s dev-loop9.device                                   
 7.894s dev-loop8.device                                   
 7.545s NetworkManager.service                             
 7.467s dev-loop5.device                                   
 7.405s dev-loop6.device                                   
 6.757s avahi-daemon.service                               
 6.653s dev-loop1.device                                   
 6.650s dev-loop3.device                                   
 6.649s dev-loop0.device                                   
 6.648s dev-loop4.device                                   
 6.644s dev-loop7.device                                   
 6.378s polkit.service                                     
 5.909s switcheroo-control.service                         
 5.816s systemd-journal-flush.service                      
 5.723s thermald.service                                   
 5.719s systemd-logind.service                             
 5.713s wpa_supplicant.service                             
 5.655s systemd-resolved.service                           
 4.796s ModemManager.service                               
 4.605s grub-common.service                                
 4.233s rsyslog.service                                    
 4.064s gpu-manager.service                                
 3.412s nmbd.service                                       
 2.913s systemd-udevd.service                              
 2.633s e2scrub_reap.service                               
 1.794s grub-initrd-fallback.service                       
 1.739s smbd.service                                       
 1.484s colord.service                                     
 1.452s snap-chromium-1182.mount                           
 1.372s snap-chromium-1192.mount                           
 1.293s snap-core18-1705.mount                             
 1.281s systemd-rfkill.service                             
 1.276s apparmor.service                                   
 1.263s snap-core18-1754.mount                             
 1.231s lm-sensors.service                                 
 1.229s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount             
 1.214s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                     
 1.183s upower.service                                     
 1.093s fwupd.service                                      
 1.090s home-rpederso-Ubuntu\x2dShare.mount                
 1.056s systemd-modules-load.service                       
  937ms systemd-timesyncd.service                          
  929ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount             
  881ms systemd-journald.service                           
  843ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount            
  823ms pppd-dns.service                                   
  715ms keyboard-setup.service                             
  688ms snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-232.mount             
  674ms snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-234.mount             
  661ms snapd.apparmor.service                             
  660ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                       
  648ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                 
  630ms swapfile.swap                                      
  606ms snap-snap\x2dstore-454.mount                       
  603ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service    
  578ms systemd-sysusers.service                           
  558ms systemd-random-seed.service                        
  544ms gdm.service                                        
  536ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                              
  476ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                       
  475ms snap-snapd-7777.mount                              
  448ms systemd-sysctl.service                             
  388ms plymouth-start.service                             
  361ms user@1000.service                                  
  334ms snap-vlc-1620.mount                                
  310ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d5\x2dstable-4.mount       
  301ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  299ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d5\x2dstable-5.mount       
  296ms ufw.service                                        
  295ms openvpn.service                                    
  295ms modprobe@drm.service                               
  260ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-136.mount         
  233ms snapd.seeded.service                               
  200ms systemd-remount-fs.service                         
  176ms dev-hugepages.mount                                
  175ms dev-mqueue.mount                                   
  172ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                             
  171ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                           
  167ms kmod-static-nodes.service                          
  158ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-145.mount         
  134ms apport.service                                     
   91ms kerneloops.service                                 
   80ms console-setup.service                              
   77ms hddtemp.service                                    
   73ms setvtrgb.service                                   
   71ms rtkit-daemon.service                               
   65ms systemd-update-utmp.service                        
   60ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                     
   56ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                      
   44ms systemd-user-sessions.service                      
   35ms plymouth-read-write.service                        
   28ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service               
   21ms alsa-restore.service                               
    9ms sys-kernel-config.mount                            
    6ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                      
    1ms snapd.socket
```

Can anyone figure out what's going on? Any idea what process(s) is taking so much time?

Comment: Is Ubuntu on SSD installed or HD ? Post the output of the following commands: systemd-analyze time and systemd-analyze blame.. btw they are not seconds

Comment: @kannzzmm2 If they are not seconds in dmesg, then what are they? Output from systemd-analyze time -->
Startup finished in 39.111s (kernel) + 2min 28.126s (userspace) = 3min 7.237s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 28.047s in userspace

Comment: @kannzzmm2 systemd-analyze blame too long to list in comment, but a few lines ->
27.601s plymouth-quit-wait.service
16.406s dev-sda5.device
16.137s snapd.service
15.810s networkd-dispatcher.service                        
15.519s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                 
11.848s udisks2.service                                    
10.759s accounts-daemon.service
10.315s dev-loop16.device
10.080s dev-loop10.device
 9.854s dev-loop14.device
 9.409s dev-loop13.device
 9.199s dev-loop11.device
 9.147s dev-loop17.device

Comment: please edit your post and then add the whole output as code section

Comment: @kannzzmm2 I edited post to show full results of systemd-analyze time and blame

Comment: It appears that the snap packages are taking a long time to start up. The `dev-loop`s are the snaps installed on your system. If you can, remove them or replace them with `.deb` packages. See this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056645/what-are-the-dev-loop-services-that-started-on-boot

Comment: now you can do the following commands: 1. sudo gedit /etc/default/grub and remove quiet splash, and run sudo update-grub
2. sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
3. reboot and check again with systemd-analyze time && blame if these two are not anymore available during the boot

Comment: @kannzzmm2 I kept searching online and ran across this article
[link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/fix-slow-boot-ubuntu-18-04/)
It turned out to be a problem with my swap partition. I had deleted the old swap partition in order to make the root partition bigger. The old boot process spent 1m 30s looking for the old partition

Answer (score 0):

I kept searching online and ran across this article

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/fix-slow-boot-ubuntu-18-04/

It turned out to be a problem with my swap partition. I had deleted the old swap partition in order to make the root partition bigger. The old boot process spent 1m 30s looking for the old partition.