# snapd: slow bootup due to snaps mounting on boot

Tags: boot, snap

I've tried to look around for ways to fix this, and nothing I've found has helped so far.

The snap daemon is causing slower boot because of the mounting. I've heard it's possible to make snaps mount on demand or spread it out after boot, but I haven't found any good resources for how to actually change this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to check what is consuming boot time.
E.g. `systemd-analyze blame` or `sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain`, see also

1. [Does snaps slow down the boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912135/does-snaps-slow-down-the-boot)
2. https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-causing-lengthy-boot-time/10466/6
3. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322732
4. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/very-slow-system-boot-with-ubuntu-mate-20-04/22415
5. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-i-can-speed-up-booting-time-and-loading-userspace-on-manjaro-kde/61214

As for how to prevent mounting at boot time, assuming snaps are the culprit, I did not find a definitive solution.
But, possibly helpful/related:

1. https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-do-i-stop-snaps-mounting-during-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04/21434
2. [Delete and recreate swap partition](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322732), probably useful if snap **is not** the culprit.
3. https://serverfault.com/questions/1044689/how-do-i-stop-snaps-mounting-during-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Even though this does not 100% answer my question, I'll accept this and grant the bounty (as the snap forum link seems to say it's not currently possible). Thanks for all the resources however! (Edit: I have to wait 7 hours to grant the bounty, so I'll do it later today)