# How to disable snap store service in bootup

Tags: 20.04, snap, snap-store

In ubuntu 20.04, Snap Store always start in boot time. How can I disable it from starting in boot?

I dont use `snap` services much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snapd: slow bootup due to snaps mounting on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337178/snapd-slow-bootup-due-to-snaps-mounting-on-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking various solutions I decided to remove `snap-store` using `snap`

`sudo snap remove snap-store`

I got not issues so far from functionality side. All other suggested options just stop `snap-store` service for short duration.

Answer (score 5):

You need to stop some services:

```
sudo systemctl disable snapd.service
sudo systemctl disable snapd.socket
sudo systemctl disable snapd.seeded.service
```

I don't know if there are side effects. Doing so, your snap apps aren't likely to start (e.g. Firefox).

The services won't be started the next time you boot.

To be on the safe side, I've removed snap completely (without loosing firefox) as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369159/how-to-remove-snap-completely-without-losing-firefox)

This would include to remove all installed snaps (e.g. Firefox) which can be installed via a ppa if you are using it.

The removal reduced the startup time on my old Thinkpad. Firefox opens faster with the deb version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the service name but all you need to do is disable the service from starting at boot time. You will still be able to start up the service manually after you boot and anything that depends on the service will also have the ability to start it as well.

```
sudo systemctl disable servicename
```

where "servicename" is the actual name of the service. I'm not familiar with the snap store service so you'll have to find out the name on your own.

As mentioned, services that depend on the service will still have the ability to start it up so it might start on its own during boot. Please let me know if this happens and maybe we can come up with a different solution instead.

If you ever need to start the service manually, you can run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start servicename
```

again, where "servicename" is the actual name of the service.

You can also check the status or stop the service:

```
sudo systemctl status servicename
```

and

```
sudo systemctl stop servicename
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this way, but not working as snap core is started and starting back store application.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Then disable snap core and you can start it after boot if you need to.